# Using $helper in CakePHP 2

Tags: helper, cakephp-2.2

I have a question about declaring $helper explicitly.
This is sample code from CakePHP Book.

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    ..
}
```

In my code, I didn't have that declaration at all, but my app is still working, I can save data via my web form, I can also using $this->Html->link().

Do I really need that declaration, any disadvantages if I didn't?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$helpers` variable only needs to be declared when you are using a Helper other than 'HTML' and 'Form'. The core helpers 'Html' and 'Form' are loaded by default into the `$helpers` array, so the declaration is unnecessary if you only intend to use these.

If you want to add a custom helper, or use any other core helper, then you must declare the `$helpers` array. When you do this, you are overwriting the default helpers array, so you need to make sure to include the defaults again if you still intend to use them.

```
// Default. You do not need to declare this if you 
// only intend to use these helpers.
$helpers = array('HTML', 'Form'); 

// Add 'CustomHelper' to $helpers array. In this case
// HTML and Form must be declared.
$helpers = array('HTML', 'Form', 'Custom');
```

Comment: What if I need to use Session helper???
$helpers = array('Session');
or
$helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
Do I have to repeat declaring 'Html' and 'Form'???

Comment: Yes, you have to repeat Html and Form. So, if you wish to use the Session helper, the declaration should be `$helper = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session')`.

Comment: I need to use myCustom helper in all views, so I added it in appController, but it is giving errors related to Auth, is there some different way to access custom helper in all views